# Is there any alternative to provide user and password to Hibernate reactive without persistance.xml?

Tags: security, reactive-programming, persistence.xml, hibernate-reactive

I am trying to figure out a way to provide user and password without hardcoding them on the same server. I need to fetch them through an api.

```
            <!-- MySQL -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase"/>

            <!-- Credentials -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
                      value="this is user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                      value="this is password"/>
```

Above is how it is being done right now but I want to wire these so anyone who has code access still can't see the user and password. How can I achieve that? I don't have JPA in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure precisely what you’re requirements are, but a very flexible option is to implement a `RectiveConnectionPool`.

https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_custom_connection_management_and_multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this method of `javax.persistence.Persistence`:

```
/**
     * Create and return an EntityManagerFactory for the named persistence unit
     * using the given properties.
     * 
     * @param persistenceUnitName
     *            the name of the persistence unit
     * @param properties
     *            Additional properties to use when creating the factory. 
     *            These properties may include properties to control
     *            schema generation.  The values of these properties override 
     *            any values that may have been configured elsewhere.
     * @return the factory that creates EntityManagers configured according to
     *         the specified persistence unit.
     */
    public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
```

Fetch the username and password from your API and store them in a `Map` like this:

```
    var props = new HashMap<String, String>();
    fetch("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", props);
    fetch("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", props);
    fetch("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", props);
```

and then call:

```
    emf = Persistence
        .createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate-config", props)
```